# What is the fastest way to get local style name from range with Word VSTO or WordOpenXML

Tags: ms-word, interop, vsto, openxml

I had a solution that got the runtime paraId and then used that to find local stylename in openXML but it seems that it can be missing and I don't know how to make sure it is always there. This is acceptable speed when it is working (after loading officeOpenXMl around ~1-2ms per range). See previous post:
[Word VSTO - Why paraId is sometimes missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136802/word-vsto-why-paraid-is-sometimes-missing/50138183?noredirect=1#comment87301323_50138183)

I need the style for each paragraph in a selected range. `Paragraph.range.wordopenxml` would work, but it is more inefficient than range.get_style(); ~60-70ms per range.

I have tried `range.get_style()` but this also is too slow ~20-30ms per range.

```
Word.Range selectedRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;

Word.Range firstPara = selectedRange.Paragraphs.First.Range;
Word.Range lastPara = selectedRange.Paragraphs.Last.Range;

while (firstPara.Start <= lastPara.Start)
{
   //I need to get the style NameLocal for paragraph in this range (firstPara).

    firstPara.MoveStart(Word.WdUnits.wdParagraph, 1);
    firstPara.MoveEnd(Word.WdUnits.wdParagraph, 1);
}
```

Comment: Mmm. The *order* of the paragraphs in the open document and in the WordOpenXML will be exactly the same. You can address any member of a Word collection (`Paragraphs`  in this case) by its oridinal (base 1, remember). So if you use `Selection.Range.WordOpenXML` and "loop" all those paragraphs with a counter and the style name (into an array or dict or whatever) you should have a match for `Selection.Range.Paragraphs`. So the style for counter value 1 = `Selection.Range.Paragraphs[1].Style.NameLocal`.

Comment: Beyond that, referring to your code, to get the style names of each paragraph in a Selection: `foreach (Word.Paragraph para in Selection.Range.Paragraphs) { string stylename = para.Range.Style.NameLocal; }`  - more efficient than what you show...

Comment: There is no para.Range.Style in my language version, but the first suggestion you gave was gold.  When tables came in to play the WordOpenXML paragraph tags count did not match the range.paragraph count. There were a few exceptions for range.paragraph has extra "\r\a" row endings that are paragraphs but the XML does not have this. But I think i got it right now! Will be updating a "solution" here. Thanks!

Comment: para = variable name for a `Paragraph` object.